# Random string saved as session regenerates on page refresh

Tags: php, html

I am generating five random characters using the `uniqid` function and saving it as a session as I need to retain it *(keep it)* when the page refreshes due to a form being submitted.

The only problem is... each time the page is refreshed (due to the form being submitted) a new set of five random characters are generated!

```
<?php
$_SESSION['string'] = substr(uniqid('', true), -5);
echo $_SESSION['string'];
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Note: I cannot include the characters in a URL variable and cannot show the characters to the user other than when I do in the code above (this rules out the option of placing the characters in a hidden input element).

Comment: Because you generate it every time the page loads. You want to set it only if it does not exist already: `if (!isset($_SESSION['string'])) { $_SESSION['string'] = substr(uniqid('', true), -5); }`

Comment: Please note that `uniqid()` does *NOT* produce random results and this function should not be used for security. If you're looking for as close to random as possible, use http://php.net/manual/de/function.random-bytes.php.

Comment: @Mike Cheers for pointing that out. Does `uniqid()` have a pre-set of random characters which it chooses from (or something along the lines of that)?

Comment: @TheCodesee Nothing about uniqid() is random. From what I understand it is similar to a hash function based on the current time and that is how it guarantees that the result is always unique - at least on your system. Across multiple servers the numbers are not unique. The results are completely predictable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use isset:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['string']))
{
  $_SESSION['string'] = substr(uniqid('', true), -5);
}
echo $_SESSION['string'];
?>
```

Comment: Hi Jojo. This for some reason doesn't prevent the issue from happening - a new set of characters are still displayed.

Comment: you both forgot `session_start()`

Comment: Ahh @mistermartin, that's why! Good spot :)